# How to add frame image on a particular image in php?

Tags: php, gdlib

Hi friends I'm try to make an image with frame border. And try some code but its not working.

```
$src = imagecreatefrompng('centerpic.png');
$dest = imagecreatefrompng('Frame.png');

imagealphablending($dest, false);
imagesavealpha($dest, true);
$insert_x = imagesx($src); 
$insert_y = imagesy($src);


imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 10, 15, 0, 0, $insert_x, $insert_y, 100); 

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($dest);

imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
```

but output not my type..

I want to merge two image one is frame and second one is other image..

Can any one help me?

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: please look at this..http://i.imgur.com/d2kVWv9.png?1

Comment: Is that image the result of your code? Because that's not the result I get when I run your code - I get what (I think) you are aiming for.

Comment: Yes my dear friend its a result

Comment: Could you post the actual images you are using?